# UIPickerView: Sorting & displaying an array of values causes crash when moved?

Tags: objective-c, sorting, nsmutablearray, nsarray, uipickerview

I'm trying to sort an NSMutableArray of Strings into alphabetical order and display the sorted list in an UIPickerView. I'm using another NSArray to create a sorted list.

Im using the PickerView Delegate Methods and have included them in my .h setup:  and connected the dataSource & delegate outlets to the filesOwner. In my .h file I have also created an IBOutlet UIPickerView *pickerView; and created a synthesised property for it like this:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIPickerView *pickerView;
```

Trying to troubleshoot the problem, I firstly made my unsorted NSMutableArray the source by doing the following:

```
- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component {

return [pickerArray objectAtIndex:row];
}
```

My unsorted MutableArray has no issues and displays the data (unsorted) in the PickerView without problems but when I change the array to my sorted NSArray I get a crash after trying to move the PickerView!? An NSLog of the items in both arrays reveals the same number of items, the same data (displayed differently obviously) however Xcode reports a EXC_BAD_ACCESS?? I can't figure this one out??

Here is my code: (Note: sortedPickerArray is an NSArray and pickerArray is an NSMutableArray declared in my .h file)

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{

[super viewDidLoad];

sortedPickerArray = [[NSArray alloc] init];

pickerArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:
               @"ObjectA",
               @"ObjectB",
               @"ObjectC",
               @"ObjectD",
               nil];

sortedPickerArray = [pickerArray sortedArrayUsingSelector: @selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];
[pickerView selectRow:0 inComponent:0 animated:NO];
pickerView.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;}


-(NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView{

return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component{

return [sortedPickerArray count];
}

-(NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component {
return [sortedPickerArray objectAtIndex:row];
}

-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component{

NSLog(@"Row %d was selected", row);
}
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming in this answer that you're not using ARC since you have a retained property. You assign an autoreleased value to your instance variable with the statement:

`sortedPickerArray = [pickerArray sortedArrayUsingSelector: @selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];`

When you access `sortedPickerArray` later on it has already been deallocated. So, again assuming you're not using ARC, add a `retain` in there. And delete the line 
`sortedPickerArray = [[NSArray alloc] init];` as you are leaking this array as of now.

Comment: Awesome! I can't thank you enough - that did the trick! You are correct,  I wasn't using ARC! I missed that autoreleased value and that was definitely the problem. oops I forgot to delete that line (sortedPickerArray alloc) as I was shuffling between Xcode and Stackoverflow - my bad :-)

Comment: Cool! Glad I helped! Please accept the answer and upvote that will be plenty thanks!